# Set output location for python script

Tags: python

I want to save all images from a site. wget is horrible, at least for http://www.leveldesigninspirationmachine.tumblr.com since in the image folder it just drops html files, and nothing as an extension.

I found a python script, the usage is like this:

```
[python] ImageDownloader.py URL MaxRecursionDepth DownloadLocationPath MinImageFileSize
```

Finally I got the script running after some BeautifulSoup problems.
However, I can't find the files anywhere. I also tried "/" as the output dir in hope the images got on the root of my HD but no luck. Can someone either help me to simplify the script so it outputs at the cd directory set in terminal. Or give me a command that should work. I have zero python experience and I don't really want to learn python for a 2 year old script that maybe doesn't even work the way I want.

Also, how can I pass an array of website? With a lot of scrapers it gives me the first few results of the page. Tumblr has the load on scroll but that has no effect so i would like to add `/page1` etc.

thanks in advance

```
# imageDownloader.py
# Finds and downloads all images from any given URL recursively.
# FB - 201009094
import urllib2
from os.path import basename
import urlparse
#from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup # for HTML parsing
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

global urlList
urlList = []

# recursively download images starting from the root URL
def downloadImages(url, level, minFileSize): # the root URL is level 0
    # do not go to other websites
    global website
    netloc = urlparse.urlsplit(url).netloc.split('.')
    if netloc[-2] + netloc[-1] != website:
        return

    global urlList
    if url in urlList: # prevent using the same URL again
        return

    try:
        urlContent = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        urlList.append(url)
        print url
    except:
        return

    soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(urlContent))
    # find and download all images
    imgTags = soup.findAll('img')
    for imgTag in imgTags:
        imgUrl = imgTag['src']
        # download only the proper image files
        if imgUrl.lower().endswith('.jpeg') or \
            imgUrl.lower().endswith('.jpg') or \
            imgUrl.lower().endswith('.gif') or \
            imgUrl.lower().endswith('.png') or \
            imgUrl.lower().endswith('.bmp'):
            try:
                imgData = urllib2.urlopen(imgUrl).read()
                if len(imgData) >= minFileSize:
                    print "    " + imgUrl
                    fileName = basename(urlsplit(imgUrl)[2])
                    output = open(fileName,'wb')
                    output.write(imgData)
                    output.close()
            except:
                pass
    print
    print

    # if there are links on the webpage then recursively repeat
    if level > 0:
        linkTags = soup.findAll('a')
        if len(linkTags) > 0:
            for linkTag in linkTags:
                try:
                    linkUrl = linkTag['href']
                    downloadImages(linkUrl, level - 1, minFileSize)
                except:
                    pass

# main
rootUrl = 'http://www.leveldesigninspirationmachine.tumblr.com'
netloc = urlparse.urlsplit(rootUrl).netloc.split('.')
global website
website = netloc[-2] + netloc[-1]
downloadImages(rootUrl, 1, 50000)
```

Comment: The program should save the images in the same directory as the program is run. Note that you shouldn't just use `except: pass` in your program, as any errors that maybe occur during downloading is simply just supressed, with no indicator of success or failure. Especially not when trying to find problems in your programs.

Answer (score 1):

As Frxstream has commented, this program creates the files **in the current directory** (i.e. where you run it). After running the program, run `ls -l` (or `dir`) to find the files it has created.

If it seemingly hasn't created any files, then most probably it really hasn't created any files, most probably because there was an exception which your `except: pass` has hidden. To see what was going wrong, replace `try: ... except: pass` with just `...`, and rerun the program. (If you can't understand and fix that, ask a separate StackOverflow question.)

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to tell without looking at the errors (+1 to turning off your try/except block so you can see the exceptions) but I do see one typo here:

```
fileName = basename(urlsplit(imgUrl)[2])
```

you didn't do "from urlparse import urlsplit" you have "import urlparse" so you need to refer to it as urlparse.urlsplit() as you have in other places, so should be like this

```
fileName = basename(urlparse.urlsplit(imgUrl)[2])
```